# Type error in application - Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

type Car = (String, [String], Int, [String])

```
carToString :: [Car] -> IO()
carToString [] = putStr ""
carToString (x:xs) = putStr x ++ "\n" : putStr xs ++ "\n"

displayAllCars :: IO ()
displayAllCars = putStr carToString testDatabase --< test data in the format of type Car
```

this gives me the error:

```
ERROR file:.\template.hs:26 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : putStr xs
*** Term           : xs
*** Type           : [([Char],[[Char]],Int,[[Char]])]
*** Does not match : [Char]
```

What is the cause of this error and how do I correct it?

Comment: Could you describe what you intend to do with this code?

Comment: I fixed the error message formatting for you.

Comment: The function is named putSTr because it puts a String - but you do putStr xs, where xs is a list of Cars. You simply want putStr (show testDatabase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead

```
displayAllCars :: [Car] -> IO ()
displayAllCars = mapM_ (putStrLn . show)
```

naturally this generalizes to something like

```
putStrLnAll :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
putStrLnAll = mapM_ (putStrLn . show)
```

I think this does what you desire. Your code is pretty much indecipherable because the names of the functions don't match what they actually do.

An example of iterating over the Cars:

```
iter [] = ?
iter x@(v1, v2, v3, v4):xs = do stuff with x (the car) and its values v1, v2, v3, v4 then call iter xs.
```

To fold them all into a string, you probably want something like (assuming `displayCar :: Car -> String` exists). I'm again avoiding explicit recursion here in favor of using an auxiliary function.

```
displayAllCars = foldl' (\acc val -> acc ++ "\n" ++ val) []
```

However, we could use recursion: (The usual warning applies here as with any non-tail-optimized recursion function. You *will* get a stack overflow if the list is large. Use the foldl' version in production code. Alternatively foldr is the best if a backwards list is acceptable.

```
displayAllCars [] = []
displayAllCars c:cs = displayCar c ++ "\n" ++ displayCar cs
```

Comment: Ohh i see, where you said in the last comment - does this mean it wants a different type going in? I need to add the newline and also how would i reference each item inside the car type? 

I have a list of type car - how can i grab the individual items of each item car? (sorry for all the questions i am a beginner and u seem to know what ur talking about, thank you!)

Comment: @Ash what do you mean by grab the individual items of a last of car? Most likely you want to either map, fold, list comprehension, or something else using (pattern match):xs recursion.

Comment: @Ash basically what I thought was that your carToString was meant to display a car. I figured we could already do that with Show - you can implement your own routine if you want, just use that instead of a show. it should have a type of `displayCar :: Car -> String`. Then the idea is to perform a monadic map over the list of cars to display each car.

Comment: Well there is a list of Cars - i want each item in the list and to be able to get each sub item, of that item? I think that makes sense, do you see what i mean? I have tried recursion but cannot figure out how to get the sub items from the current item in the list.

Comment: @Ash what do you mean by get though? You can certainly access those items but what you do depends on what you want to do with the items? Do you want to print them? Do you want to add them? Etc? Certainly I think you are overusing the IO monad.

Comment: Okay well i basically want to make a String that is formatted similar to a table so on each newline it will have the next item - like:

item1 | item1 | item1
item2 | item2 | item2

i want to use the code very similar to what i have so i can understand it properly if you get me? is my code modifiable so it can do this for me maybe with list comprehensions?

Comment: @Ash so you want something like `displayAllCars :: [Car] -> String`? In this case you likely want a fold.

Comment: Yes that is what i had before i started using IO (). I only started using IO () because of the new line

Comment: @Ash never slip into IO unless you are doing IO :)

Comment: @Ash, first write a function that shows a single car (say showCar). Next, do map showCar myCars. The resulting list still need the newlines, so (intersperse "\n" (map showCar myCars)) and all is well.

Comment: Actually, on 2nd tought, he can save the intersperse and just mapM_ putStrLn ....

Comment: Ahhh okay i will have a go and let you know :)

Comment: when you say shows a single car do you mean give it a list and it will return 1 item recursively?

Comment: @Ingo I have that in my impure IO version, but I prefer having a way to convert to a string and then simply putStr the string. Keeps as much pure as possible.

Comment: @Ash I mean that it takes a single Car. It has type `Car -> String`.

Comment: sorry i am really struggling with this, i really cant seem to get my head around it...

Comment: @mathepic - but observe that "\n" is not necessarily the correct way to make a newline. Hence, once you have the list of strings, you can do mapm_ putStrLn or mapM_ fillListBox or mapM_ htmlTableRow or whatever.

Comment: where do i put mapM_ putStrLn??

Comment: @Ash in your output function. If it helps mapM_ has type `(a -> m b) -> [a] -> IO ()`. There is also another function, mapM, of type `(a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` (of course, `m` is a monad)

Comment: this is what i have so far and its complaining about the types:

getCar :: Car -> String
getCar f = show f

dispCars :: String
dispCars = map (getCar) testDatabase

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
putStr x ++ "\n"
```

this will be parsed like so:

```
(putStr x) ++ "\n"
```

This is probably not what you want. Try

```
putStr ( x ++ "\n" )
```

Note also that the : operator has type a -> [a] -> [a], i.e. the second operand must be a list. But you have the same kind of thing left and right of :
This would explain the exotic error message, as it induces the compiler to match an already wrong type with its list form .....

Comment: I think its something to do with me trying to iterate over the list of items with the xs method

Comment: Still won't do anything remotely like what he wants. The code is so badly broken that it won't be fixed. For example, notice that `(carToString testDatabase)` is of `IO ()`. You can't pass an `IO ()` to `putStr`. Most likely he wants something else which I will be putting up as an answer in a few seconds. +1 for an error caught though.

Comment: Actually, the : was the 2nd error in the same line, that this all should be IO () would have been the 3rd and of course, at the end he does (printStr carToString) testdatabase - I don't want to see that message :)

Comment: @Ingo yes, I noticed that as well, but I inferred he meant putStr (carToString testDatabase)

Comment: @mathepic - that is, you did  higher order semantic inference :)

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, the one problem that doesn't seem to have been pointed out yet is that you're trying to apply `putStr` (which expects a `[Char]`) to `carToString` (a function which, even after being given parameters, returns an `IO ()`).  As `carToString` already makes use of `putStr`, just get rid of the `putStr` in `displayAllCars`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
carToString :: [Car] -> [IO()]
carToString [] = [putStr ""]
carToString (x:xs) = putStr x ++ "\n" : carToString xs ++ "\n"
```

You don' need display all cars. You can just call the carToString function and pass the list of Car